# mod_dav_svn not allowing authenticated users

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, centos6, mod-dav-svn

I am running a CentOS 6.3 server along with a custom compile apache 2.4.3 (compile line below) and custom compiled subversion 1.7.8 (again, compile line below).

I have mod_dav_svn set up, and it half works. If I go to svn.domain.com/svn it asks me for my username and password. I can log in fine (it only asks me once) and I can browse through the repositories no problem. If I then go to tortoisesvn on a windows machine and try to check outa repository (svn.domain.com/svn/testrepo for example) the login window pops up. I type my credentials in and hit save and then ok. The window pops up again. I can keep typing my credentials in over and over, and it doesn't do anything (it acts like my username and password are wrong but I know they aren't). Nothing is showing up in the error log, and nothing weird is showing up in the access log.
If I disable the authentication, everything works perfectly.
Halp!

EDIT: I did a "chmod -R 777 /u01/svn" to see if that fixed the problem. No dice. The svnauth file is also 777 for the same reason.

## VHosts Configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin tony@domain.om
    DocumentRoot "/u01/www/vhosts/svn"
    ServerName svn.domain.com
    ErrorLog "logs/svn.domain.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/svn.domain.com-access_log" common
    <Location /svn>
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath /u01/svn/
        SVNListParentPath On
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Subversion repository"
        AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/conf/svnauth
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

## Configure switches

Apache

```
"./configure" \
"--prefix=/usr/local/apache" \
"--enable-ssl" \
"--enable-rewrite=shared" \
"--enable-status=shared" \
"--enable-info=shared" \
"--enable-so"
```

Subversion

```
'./configure' \
'--with-serf' \
'--enable-ssl' \
'--prefix=/usr/local/subversion' \
'--with-apr=/usr/local/apache/bin/apr-1-config' \
'--with-apr-util=/usr/local/apache/bin/apu-1-config'
```

## Directory Listing Results

```
[pritchea@server ~]$ ls -l /u01/svn/
total 12
drwxrwxrwx 6 pritchea wheel 4096 Jan 24 04:44 repo1
drwxrwxrwx 6 pritchea wheel 4096 Jan 15 03:20 repo2
drwxrwxrwx 6 pritchea wheel 4096 Mar  7 20:13 testrepo
[pritchea@server ~]$ ls -l /u01/svn/*
/u01/svn/repo1:
total 24
drwxrwxrwx 2 pritchea wheel 4096 Jan 24 04:44 conf
drwxrwxrwx 6 pritchea wheel 4096 Jan 24 04:51 db
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pritchea wheel    2 Jan 24 04:44 format
drwxrwxrwx 2 pritchea wheel 4096 Jan 24 04:44 hooks
drwxrwxrwx 2 pritchea wheel 4096 Jan 24 04:44 locks
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pritchea wheel  229 Jan 24 04:44 README.txt

/u01/svn/repo2:
total 24
drwxrwxrwx 2 pritchea wheel 4096 Jan 15 03:20 conf
drwxrwxrwx 6 pritchea wheel 4096 Feb 12 02:26 db
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pritchea wheel    2 Jan 15 03:20 format
drwxrwxrwx 2 pritchea wheel 4096 Jan 15 03:20 hooks
drwxrwxrwx 2 pritchea wheel 4096 Jan 15 03:20 locks
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pritchea wheel  229 Jan 15 03:20 README.txt

/u01/svn/testrepo:
total 24
drwxrwxrwx 2 pritchea wheel 4096 Mar  7 20:13 conf
drwxrwsrwx 6 pritchea wheel 4096 Mar  7 20:13 db
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pritchea wheel    2 Mar  7 20:13 format
drwxrwxrwx 2 pritchea wheel 4096 Mar  7 20:13 hooks
drwxrwxrwx 2 pritchea wheel 4096 Mar  7 20:13 locks
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pritchea wheel  229 Mar  7 20:13 README.txt
```

Comment: That all looks fine.  A couple more things on the checklist: `httpd -M` and check for `dav_module`, `dav_svn_module`, `auth_basic_module`.  Also, since it works with a browser but fails with TortoiseSVN, can you try with a different client and/or upgrade TortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the `DocumentRoot` directive.  It's not valid with `DAV svn`.

Comment: No Dice. 
Exact same thing happens. I've used the documentroot directive before without an issue. It doesn't matter if it's in there though, since I won't be using it as a host for anything other than svn.

Comment: What do you get for `ls -l /u01/svn/` and `ls -l /u01/svn/*`?

Comment: I just updated my original post with the results of those commands

Comment: Well, apart from the DocumentRoot (which was the cause of the last problem I had with `DAV svn`), the `SVNListParentPath On` that I don't have and the SSL stuff that I have and you don't, your vhost is identical to mine.  And your `SVNParentPath` is pointed correctly.

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer as right. I was trying to connect to the repository from work. I use tortoisesvn at work all the time and it works great. I just tried it from home using eclipse (with subclipse) and it worked. I have no idea what the problem is, though. I'm assuming that there's something in our work firewall that is blocking the connection. Oh well, it works. Thanks for your help! I probably would have kept banging my head against the wall before I tried connecting from home!